# How post JSON array to ASP.Net Core app using Postman

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, postman

I am new in ASP.Net Core development. I want to post array of custom class to ASP.Net controller. I can post object but not array.

Here is my `InventoryItem` class

```
public class InventoryItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my method in `InventoryController` Class

```
public ActionResult<InventoryItem> AddInventoryItems([FromForm]InventoryItem[] items)
{
    return Ok("Array Length " + items.Length);
}
```

I am getting Array Length as 0.

I am using Postman

[image]

Also I have tried Posting data as JSON and modifying `[FromForm]` to `[FromBody]` attribute:

Also I am getting **415 Unsupported Media Type** error in Postman when changed to `[FromBody]`.
[image]

Comment: You are sending it as `form-data`, instead use raw and post a json array.

Comment: You should decide if you wana post JSON or form data ... also obviously `AddInventoryItems` doesn't expect JSON

Comment: Using the JSON route change the InventoryController to public ActionResult<InventoryItem> AddInventoryItems([FromBody]List<InventoryItem> items)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question in detail how I solved the problem.

There was no problem in C# code, only method of posting data in Postman was wrong.

Refer to this answer if **415 Unsupported Media Type** Error arises in Postman. C# code is same as in the Question above.

I am using two ways to post data. Firstly posting as Form-data, secondly posting in JSON  format.

1] When posting Array of custom class using form data use Xueli Chen's method Select `Body` -> `form-data` in Postman and enter array items as `items[index].key = value` like `items[0].id = 1001` and `items[0].ItemName = "Biscuits"`

[image: See here]

2] When posting array of custom class in JSON format firstly select `Body` -> `raw` -> Select `JSON` in Languages. If there is warning sign when JSON is selected like [image: this]

then Go To `Headers` -> Set `Content-Type = application/json` just like

[image]

Now `Body` -> `raw` JSON Array Data

```
[
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "ItemName": "Biscuits",
        "Price": 20
    },
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "ItemName": "Cakes",
        "Price": 100
    }
]
```

and in C# code in the project change `[FromForm]` to `[FromBody]` attribute

```
public ActionResult<InventoryItem> AddInventoryItems([FromBody]InventoryItem[] items)
```

and Send to the Server [image]

In short for Posting Array as `form-data` use `items[index].key = value` like `items[0].ItemName = Biscuits` in Postman.

For Posting Array as JSON Data Enter JSON array and check if `Content-Type = application/json` in `Headers` in Postman.

Sorry for the long answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying in a wrong way. As you are trying to pass data to your controller which is a collection type. So  you have to pass a `Json` array to meet your controller data type. You can do it in following way.

Select `Body` then `Raw` then `Json` If you want to pass `Json` data. your array

should look like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "itemName": "A",
    "price": 10.0
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "itemName": "B",
    "price": 20.0
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "itemName": "C",
    "price": 30.0
  }
]
```

***See the screen shot:***

[image]

***`Test Result`***

[image]

I have tried as per your sample which works fine:

```
        [HttpPost("[action]")]
        [Route("AddInventoryItems")]
        [ActionName("AddInventoryItems")]
        public ActionResult<InventoryItem> AddInventoryItems([FromBody]InventoryItem [] items)
        {
            return Ok("Array Length " + items.Count());

        }
```

***`Final Output:`***

[image]

I have tested many ways all works fine. I have attached code as well you could try.

*`But apart from your question I would suggest you to write your controller like below which mostly practice in C# and Web API`*

```
        [HttpPost("[action]")]
        [Route("AddInventoryItems")]
        [ActionName("AddInventoryItems")]
        public ActionResult<InventoryItem> AddInventoryItems([FromBody]List<InventoryItem> items)
        {
            return Ok("Array Length " + items.Count());

        }
```

Comment: Pictures are fine if they supplement text explaining them. Users with vision issues or otherwise using screen readers will hear "You are trying in a wrong way. Try below way. enter image description here". Which doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron, As I said, it works when I post single object and not array. The problem comes when I Post array of `InventoryItems`. Also, I tried posting as JSON, I got same problem array size is 0.

Comment: I have updated answer and tested this way I got expected output. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

1.Get data in `[FromForm]` , you should pass the array data as below format in postman:
[image]

2.Pass the data as JSON, you should use `[FromBody]` attribute as Md Farid Uddin Kiron suggested above:

```
public ActionResult<InventoryItem> AddInventoryItems([FromBody]InventoryItem[] items)
 {
        return Ok("Array Length " + items.Length);
 }
```

Comment: But is it a common practice or efficient way? What if there are 10 items in array?

Comment: @Xueli Chen, that's the answer I was looking. I was not getting how to send array as Form Data in Postman. Thanks. But however when I post JSON data selecting `Body` -> `raw` and modifying `[FromForm]` to `[FromBody]` in C# code, I get "415 Unsupported Media type" error in Postman. See Here "https://imgur.com/a/Jub3aMZ" and my code See here "https://imgur.com/a/G4BtLF4". Posting data using Form works, but Posting JSON Data using `[FromBody]` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are using wrong way to send data as a POST request. You can use `raw` instead of `form-data` and post a json array of your `InventoryItem`.

[image]

Comment: As I said, it works when I post single object and not array. The problem comes when I Post array of `InventoryItems`. Also I tried posting as JSON, I got same problem array size is 0.